# What do you call disciplining children by preventing them from accessing a certain toy?

Tags: word-request

**What do you call disciplining children by preventing them from accessing a certain toy?** I thought about "grounding children" but it means preventing them from going outdoors.  This is not what I mean because they can go outdoors but they can't use their RC car.

Comment: grounding is not "going outdoors"; It's for teenagers and means "not going out" with their friends, for example. Little kids are not grounded. To be grounded, you have to be old enough to go out on your own, without supervision. There is no term for what you are looking for. You just say: You can go outdoors but you can't use your RC car.

Answer (score 2):

"Taking away" toys or privileges seems to be the most common phrase to express this (as in [this example](https://www.verywellfamily.com/taking-away-privileges-to-discipline-children-1094759) or [this one](https://www.scholastic.com/parents/family-life/social-emotional-learning/praise-and-discipline/behavior-problems-discipline-works.html)). See the following examples from these sources:

- "Taking away toys"
- "take away a fun event"
- "take away their school-issued Chromebook"